# Implement SearchView for a bunch of TextViews

Tags: java, android, search, view

I have several `TextView`s inside an `Activity` with a `ScrollView`.
My goal is to have a `SearchBar` at the end of the `ScrollView` that can search through the `TextView`s.
The tutorials I found on the Internet always build a menu, which isn't my goal here.
Is it possible to set this `SearchView` up and if so, how?

Merry Christmas,
Julian.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the most appropriate way of implementing this is to create the `SearchView` in the menu, using the `Strings` in your `TextViews` as the search queries. With the `SearchView` in the menu, if you search for something and there are more results than fit on the screen, you would scroll down, but would still be able to see your search query at the top of the screen. Thus you don't have to scroll back up to perform a different search.

Comment: So you mean in the menu.xml file or is there a way to get into the menu java file?

Comment: You definitely add the `SearchView` inside the menu.xml file. Then in the Activity you would override the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method so you can start working with the `SearchView`.

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate your question properly. If you want a SearchView at the end of TextViews then just simply add it in your layout file.

Comment: Yes, but by simply adding it there, it won't be able to search. That's what I want to learn.

Comment: Here is the proper way to use this functionality, https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html